# How to fetch image from website in my application

Tags: react-native, web

I want to display all the images which are there in my website in my React Native Application... Can any one please suggest me method to do this.. Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native has an `Image` component that you can use to display images in the app. `Image` uses a prop called `source` where you can provide the source for the image. If your website is hosted online and the images are accessible via URLs, e.g. https://www.yourwebsite.com/image.png, then you can access this in your app like this:

```
<Image
  source={{uri: 'https://www.yourwebsite.com/image.png'}}
/>
```

Or if there aren't a lot of images, you can copy them in React Native project directory and refer to them using `require` like this:

```
<Image
  source={require('/assets/images/image.png')}
/>
```

[Here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) are the official docs. Go through them for details.